# Submit one array for each selected checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

I'm new to php and I'm building a form in which I need to send a pair of values when the user checks a checkbox.

Currently I have the following code (in the form page)...

```
$value = array('title' => $title, 'year' => $year);
echo("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"options[]\" value=\"$value\"/>);
```

And in the next page...

```
foreach($_REQUEST['options'] as $key => $value) {
    $title = $value['title'];
    $year = $value['year'];
    echo("$title ($year)<br/>");
}
```

From the output, it seems that it is sending just the word "array" and not the data.

Is there any way to send and array as a checkbox value, or is there any better design to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Why do you need an array to be sent for the value? Surely the choice is the one they select?

Comment: $_REQUEST['options'] is a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use $value in the echo command, it has to convert the array into a string. PHP does this by just turning it into the string "Array". If you look at the resulting HTML, will see that it actually says .

Assuming that your title and year will never have commas, an easy way to fix this would be to implode() the array with commas before putting it into the HTML, then explode() the posted data back into the original array:

```
$value =implode(',',  array($title, $year));
echo("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"options[]\" value=\"$value\"/>);

//later on...

foreach($_REQUEST['options'] as $key => $value) {
  list($title, $year) = explode(',', $value);
  echo("$title ($year)<br/>");
}
```

Comment: I can't grant the title won't have commas or other special characters. In that case then maybe I need to rethink my approach.